# Reason for a 0 return value in SaveChanges() in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I find the reason for a 0 return value in *SaveChanges()* method of **DbContext**?

When I try to add a record to a database table, *SaveChanges()* method just returns 0.

Is there any way to find out  why the record is not added, updated or deleted?

Comment: It's hard to tell when you don't show us your code.

However, SaveChanges() only returns 0 when no data was modified.
So you either did not change any data or you have an error in your code.

Comment: ok i send some of code , but this is a general question @makz

Comment: You did not ask a general question, so you cannot expect a general answer.

SaveChanges() always returnes the number of rows modified. If it returnes 0, you didn't modify anything.

If you expect EF to modify some data you probably have an error in your code. The best way to find out is to debug your code.

Comment: The code you added is not enough. We need to see whether you created the Context object correctly.

My guess is that the _Session object was added before Context object started to track changes. Then it is not recognized anymore.

Comment: thank @makzr look at answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SaveChanges method return the number of rows affected. But you can create logs use  `DbContext.Database.Log` property and see what you send to database, assuming your code is fine. Anyway good to see what we sending to database:

```
using (var context = new Context()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 

    // your code
}
```

> The DbContext.Database.Log property can be set to a delegate for any method that takes a string. Most commonly it is used with any TextWriter by setting it to the “Write” method of that TextWriter. All SQL generated by the current context will be logged to that writer.

Here you find more [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx)